# Why does the child of this class does not print?

Tags: c++, class, fork

I have made a class that is supposed to handle a subprocess but when I put a test print inside nothing happens, can someone tell me why ?

I have tried different types of print and combinations of fflush but it didn't solve the problem.

Here are my files:

Kitchen.cpp

```
Kitchen::Kitchen()
{
    int wstatus;

    this->_pid = fork();
    if (this->_pid == 0) {
        std::cout << "child: " << this->_pid << std::endl;
    } else if (this->_pid == -1) {
        throw("No child");
    } else {
        std::cout << "parent: " << this->_pid << std::endl;
        waitpid(this->_pid, &wstatus, 1);
    }
}

Kitchen::~Kitchen()
{
    if (this->_pid > 0)
        kill(this->_pid, SIGKILL);
}
```

Kitchen.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

class Kitchen {
    public:
        Kitchen();
        ~Kitchen();
    private:
        pid_t _pid;
};
```

Reception.cpp

```
int Reception::run_shell(void)
{
    this->_kitchens.push_back(Kitchen());
    return (0);
}
```

Reception.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "Kitchen.hpp"

class Reception
{
    public:
        Reception();
        ~Reception();
        void repart(std::vector<Package> packed_order);
        bool is_order(std::string input);
        std::vector<Package> pack(std::string input);
        int run_shell(void);
    private:
        std::vector<Kitchen> _kitchens;
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main(void)
{
    Reception reception;
    return (reception.run_shell());
}
```

Right now only the parent prints where as I would like both process to print.

Note that this code works outside of the class.

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: I did try though I don't use gdb very often and I am not sure what it is telling me especially with multiple processes

Comment: You have tagged this post as C++, which has threads and join,  but not fork nor waitpid,  (And why the printf?)  There are times to use these *inux calls, like when you have requirements to keep them, or your efforts are to 'nurse' some ancient code to last a little longer.  But not for new efforts, not for learning c++.  Kudo's on "class Kitchen" (what little we see of it).  However, a [MCVE] should  compile.

Comment: @2785528 is it better now ?

Comment: Handling exceptions in a ctor (i.e. Kitchen::Kitchen), such as 'fork fails' (for any reason) can be a challenge, as a ctor 'returns' no status.  Exceptions during ctor should leave the class in a known state (?not sure how, but assert works for me ;)  I think the convention in this situation, is that you should separate fork() to another function.  I did not try, and I will assign to you the research for "how handle a ctor exception?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it better now ?

Yes,  better.

---

I copied your code to my Lubuntu 18.04, and using g++ 7.3.0-27, got the thing to compile.

**The copied code on my system reproduced your error.**

Hmmm.

So, I went looking for, and quickly found, my most recent experiment with fork.  I do not understand why it works, and yours does not, they look similar enough to me.

I use a switch instead of your nested if-then-else's ... perhaps there exists a glitch in the nested if-then-else's?  a faulty char transfer?  But I doubt it.

---

So ... for pragmatic reasons, I (minimally?) changed your code to match my example.

Perhaps you can ask a better question as to why this seems to work, and in your version does not.

Hope this helps:

```
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_chrono.hh"
using  namespace std::chrono_literals;      // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30us

#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::flush, std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <thread>
using std::this_thread::sleep_for;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <cstring>
using std::strerror;

#include <unistd.h>   // fork
#include <sys/wait.h> // waitpid

#include <cassert>


class Kitchen
{
   pid_t child_pid;
   time_t pt0; // child  start time 0
   time_t ct0; // parent start time 0

public:
   Kitchen()
      {
         pt0 = time(0) + 2;
         ct0 = time(0) + 1;

         // On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the
         // parent, and 0 is returned in the child.
         //
         // On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is
         // created, and errno is set appropriately.

         child_pid = fork();

         switch (child_pid)
         {

         case -1: { errnoExit (errno, "\n  fork fail: ", -12); } break;

         case 0: // child
         {
            std::cout << "\n  i am child: " << child_pid << endl;
            ChildProcess();
         }
         break;

         default: // parent
         {
            std::cout << "\n  i am parent, child_pid: " << child_pid << flush;
            ParentProcess();
         }

         } // switch(child_pid)

      } // Kitchen

   ~Kitchen()
      {
         if (child_pid > 0)
         {   }; //  {  kill(child_pid, SIGKILL)};
      }

   void  ChildProcess(void)
      {
         int   i = 0;
         do {
            i += 1;
            cout  << "\n  child  " << i;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
            if (time(0) > ct0) break;
         }while (true);
         cout << "\n*** Child  complete ***" << '\n';
      }

   void  ParentProcess(void)
      {
         int   i = 0;
         do {
            i += 1;
            cout  << "\n  parent " << i ;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
            if (time(0) > pt0) break;
         }while (true);
         int wstatus;
         waitpid(child_pid, &wstatus, 1); // see output -
         // waitpid not effective because parent runs longer than child
         // but causes no harm ...
         //
         // TBD - when parent run is shorter than child?
         //       appears that parent end halts child?
         cout << "\n*** Parent complete ***" << '\n';
      }


private:

   void errnoExit(int err_no, const string message, int id) {
      assert(0 != err_no);  cerr << message << strerror(err_no);
      assert(id < 0);       exit(id); }

}; // class Kitchen


class Reception
{
public:
   Reception() = default;
   ~Reception() = default;

   int operator()(int argc, char* argv[]) { return run_shell(argc, argv); }

   //void repart(std::vector<Package> packed_order);
   //bool is_order(std::string input);
   //std::vector<Package> pack(std::string input);
   int run_shell(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv[]*/)
      {
         _kitchens.push_back(Kitchen());
         return (0);
      }
private:
   vector<Kitchen> _kitchens;
}; // class Reception


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { return Reception()(argc, argv); }
```

Typical Output:

```
  i am parent, child_pid: 6727

  i am child: 0

  parent 1
  child  1
  parent 2
  child  2
  parent 3
  child  3
  parent 4
  child  4
  parent 5
  child  5
  parent 6
  child  6
  parent 7
  child  7
  parent 8
  child  8
  parent 9
  child  9
  parent 10
  child  10
  parent 11
  child  11
  parent 12
  child  12
  parent 13
  child  13
  parent 14
  child  14
  parent 15
  child  15
  parent 16
  child  16
  parent 17
  child  17
  parent 18
  child  18
*** Child  complete ***
  parent 19
  parent 20
  parent 21
  parent 22
  parent 23
  parent 24
  parent 25
  parent 26
  parent 27
  parent 28
*** Parent complete ***
```

Comment: The destructor killing the child seemed to be the problem, once the kill signal removed it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The last else lacks curly braces, `waitpid(this->_pid, wstatus, 1);` is executed by both child and parent...

Comment: This as been corrected, it was not the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

The parent process needs to be told to wait for any child processes to complete. I noticed your final else condition is missing the parentheses so only the one line after the else will be executed.

The other issue is the pointer wstatus. Because it's a pointer that isn't initialized, I'm not sure which behavior will be expressed. Change it to an int and in the waitpid call, use &wstatus.

Comment: This was an error, it as been corrected and was not the source of the problem

Comment: I've tried this as well, it isn't the problem either, however I did edit my answer to specify that the code works outside of the class so the problem might be forking inside a class.

Comment: By using the arrow, you're implying that you'll be using pointers to a kitchen object. I suspect the same issue arises here with pointers that aren't initialized. Can you replace all pointers with the static data type and test? You said the code works outside the class, so this is the only other issue I can see.

Comment: there has been some updates to the question, you may want to read it again.

Comment: I can't explain the Post error, but I submitted a code that 'forks' in a class function and that seems to compile and work.